# command line to configure Windows Xp wireless client

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

Where can I find the commands to configure the wireless client on a Windows XP laptop? 
I need to change the profile several times a day and want to write a script for the same, instead of using the GUI.
Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1):

[netsh](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true) is the command line utility to use.

Vista lets you export/import profiles with xml which would make this easy, but you'll have to figure out how to go the long way :)